# Weak convergence of measures and tensor product of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We consider a sequence of measures $\{\nu_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on a topological space $X$ (endowed with the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra), converging weakly to a non-null measure $\nu$, in the sense that 
$$
\int_{X}f(t)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(t)\longrightarrow
\int_{X}f(t)\mathrm{d}\nu(t)
$$
for all real-valued continuous function $f$ on $X$.

In parallel, we consider a set of bounded (real-valued) continuous functions $\{g_{l}\}_{l\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $X$, such that for all $x$ and $t\in X$, we have
$$
0\leqslant K(x,t)=\sum_{l\in\mathbb{N}}g_{l}(x)g_{l}(t)\leqslant B, 
$$ 
for a given strictly positive real $B$; we also know that the function $K:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous for the product topology (and that its diagonal is continuous).

We moreover assume that there exists a strictly positive real $M$ such that 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{X\times X}K(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(t)
 \leqslant M\text{ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,}\\
\text{and }&\int_{X\times X}K(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(t)
 \leqslant M,
\end{align*}

**Question:** By definition, for all $l\in\mathbb{N}$, we have 
$$
\int_{X\times X}g_{l}(x)g_{l}(t)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(t)=
\bigg(\int_{X}g_{l}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(x)\bigg)^{2}\geqslant 0, 
$$
and thus, in particular,
$$
\int_{X\times X}g_{l}(x)g_{l}(t)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(t)
\stackrel{n}{\longrightarrow}
\int_{X\times X}g_{l}(x)g_{l}(t)\mathrm{d}\nu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(t);
$$
but do we have 
$$
\int_{X\times X}K(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{n}(t)\longrightarrow
\int_{X\times X}K(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\,\,?
$$

**Remark 1:** We also know that 
$$
\int_{X\times X}K(x,t)\mathrm{d}\nu(x)\mathrm{d}\nu(t)
\leqslant\bigg(\int_{X}\sqrt{K(t,t)}\mathrm{d}\nu(t)\bigg)^2, 
$$

similar type inequalities being also verified when $\nu$ is replaced by $\nu_{n}$ (the right-hand-side of the inequality being always finite).

**Remark 2:** For simplicity, we might assume that $X$ is compact.

**Remark 3:** In fact, $K$ is the kernel of a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

If $\nu(X)<\infty$, this is easy; 
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \int g_\ell d\nu_n = \sum_{\ell=1}^L \int g_\ell\, d\nu_n + \sum_{\ell=L}^\infty \int g_\ell \, d\nu_n, $$ 
and the last summand can be bounded by 
$$
\left(\sup|\sum_{\ell=L}^\infty g_\ell |\right) \nu_n(X), $$ 
which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $L$ sufficiently big, because the series $\sum g_\ell$ converges and $\nu_n(X)$ is uniformly bounded. (The tensor power version of this statement is proven with the same argument).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Guiseppe. For all $x\in X$, $\sum_{l}g_{l}(x)g_l$ converges uniformly, but we can generally not draw any conclusion for $\sum_{l}g_l$.

Comment: Ok, it was just my laziness, this argument can be rewritten with the tensor product. My point is that, since the series converges uniformly, the tail of the summation can be made arbitrarily small and it does not interfere with the convergence. Hope it is clear, I wrote in a hurry.

Comment: If the convergence of $\sum_{l}g_{l}\otimes g_{l}$ is uniform and if the measures are all finite with bounded total masses, that indeed works. I am interested in a more general setting, where K can vanish and the measures be non-finite, but I need more assumptions for this. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @DaliD.: You're welcome. Indeed, in the general setting you mention I am fairly sure you need more assumptions. As before, your "enemy" is the tail of the summation, if it is allowed to become arbitrarily big it may mess up with the convergence, so to speak.